# PowerShell - How to Update a file based on content from another file

Tags: regex, powershell

I've searched all over including here at StackOverFlow and I cannot seem to find the solution I am needing help with.  Here is my issue.

Lets say in **File1.txt** I have the following (no spaces between each line)

```
\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\032383\2200018023.pdf
\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\032383\2200718091.pdf
\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\030684\2300309040.pdf
\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\031274\2300429971.pdf
```

**File2.txt** will have the same information, however, I am needing to add a `1` right before the `.pdf` for each one (within file2.txt)

Example:
`\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\032383\22000180231.pdf`

I can easily update file2.txt using a RegEx statement, however it's only updating the contents based on that RegEx statement.

File2.txt will have a lot more data in it than file1.txt (more of the exact type of information).  I am only needing to update file2.txt adding in the `1` right before `.pdf` BASED on what is in file1.txt

Here is the code I am using but as you can see it does not read file1.txt at all, I'm just using a RegEx statement to update file2.txt adding in the 1 before .pdf  (the code below works to add in the 1 before .pdf, but I'm not iterating through file1.txt)

```
clear-host
set-location c:\temp

$File = "C:\Temp\file1.txt"
$FileZ = "C:\Temp\file2.txt"
$File2 = (Get-ChildItem $fileZ) | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName
$regex01 = '(\\Serv02\LOC6\Client\726C30\\d{1,6}\\d{1,10})(.pdf)$'
get-content $fileZ | % { $_ -replace $regex01, '${1}1${2}' -join "`r`n" } | out-file -Encoding default "c:\Temp\$File2.txt"
start-sleep -Seconds 2
$NewMRC = Get-ChildItem "$file2.txt" | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
Get-ChildItem $NewMRC | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".txt",".MRC2"}
```

If file1.txt had another line that didn't match up to the RegEx as shown above, file2.txt would not be updated with that line

`\\Serv03\LOC7\Client\780D30\031456\8675309123.pdf`

I hope I have explained this well enough.  I'm not new to PowerShell but I am far from an expert.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The contents of file1.txt has three ``\`` characters at the beginning of each line?

Comment: No each line only has two backslashes indicating server name.  This is my first post and it looked like the site was dropping off the first back slash so I added another, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Please edit your question to remove blank lines and extra ``\`` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code as follows. The approach is read the content of `File1.txt` and store it in a variable. Then iterate on each line of `File2.txt` to check it against the regex as well as if that line is present in file1 content. If yes then replace it with whatever you want. Output this to a `.tmp` file in append mode. Once all the lines in `File2.txt` are processed, then replace it with `.tmp` file.

```
clear-host
set-location c:\temp

$File = "file1.txt"
$FileZ = "file2.txt"

# PS2
$File1 = get-content $File | Out-String
# PS3
# $File1 = get-content $File -Raw

$File2 = (Get-ChildItem $fileZ) | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName

if( test-path "$File2.tmp" ) { remove-item "$File2.tmp" }

$regex01 = '(\\\\Serv02\\LOC6\\Client\\726C30\\\d{1,6}\\\d{1,10})(.pdf)$'
get-content $fileZ |% { 
    $line = $_
    $find = $line -replace '\\','\\'
    if ( ($line -match $regex01) -AND ( $File1 -match $find ) ) {
        $line -replace $regex01,'${1}1${2}' -join "`r`n" 
    } else {
        $line
    }
} | out-file "$File2.tmp" -append

remove-item "$File2.txt"
rename-item "$File2.tmp" "$File2.txt"

#start-sleep -Seconds 2
#$NewMRC = Get-ChildItem "$file2.txt" | Select -ExpandProperty Name
#Get-ChildItem $NewMRC | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".txt",".MRC2"}
```

Notes:

- The last 3 lines of your code doesn't seem to be related to your problem statement. So I've commented those lines.
- `$find = $line -replace '\\','\\'`: We are replacing single backslash `\` with double backslash `\\`. But in the first parameter to `-replace` it must be escaped and in second param it must NOT be. So, even though they look same, they are interpreted differently.

Comment: @DataLore did that help you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  Yes, however I had to switch $file and $FileZ :)  thanks

Comment: I got another scenario for you.  Let's say file2.txt has 100 filenames in it.  these file names have a _0 or _1 before .pdf how can I use that information in file2.txt to UPDATE the same info in file1.txt?  Example.  let says file1.txt on line one has 1234567890.pdf but file2.txt on line one has 1234567890_0.pdf - how do you read that and update the content in file1.txt? using the same type of REGEX in my previous question / example - - thank you

Comment: @DataLore Wow. You replied after a month, gr8. :) ... if it helped please upvote / mark as answer. As for the new scenario, it's not very clear what you want. Please put up a new question and explain your requirement in detail.

Comment: ya my job is very demanding.. work 7 days a week.  IT life.. gotta love it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this: Retrieve file content of first file into an array, then retrieve content of second file. For each line in second file: If first file's content has a line matching the current line, output modified line; otherwise, just output the current line.

```
$pattern = '(\\{2}(?:[^\\]+\\)+)([^\\\.]+)(\.pdf)'
$file1Content = Get-Content "file1.txt"
Get-Content "file2.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  if ( $file1Content -contains $_ ) {
    $_ | Select-String $pattern | ForEach-Object {
      "{0}{1}1{2}" -f
        $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value,
        $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value,
        $_.Matches[0].Groups[3].Value
    }
  }
  else {
    $_
  }
}
```

First match group (`$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value`) is `\\servername\sharename\path`, second match group is filename without extension, and third match group is the file extension.